# Android Vertical Pager Adapter (add different page in between the pager adapter)

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a requirement of showing an Advertisement between the pages of vertical pager.
example is news app like inshorts.
any way to do that.

the data used for the news page are the title, content and date, for which i am getting in a jsonarray for multiple news. my requirement is to add a different page (advertisement page) inside the pager adapter. eg: after 5 swipes of the news. i should be getting the advertisement page, which is different from the news page

Comment: please share data which are use in vertical pager like title,detail (json).

Comment: @NikhilVadoliya . the data used for the news page are the title, content and date, for which i am getting in a jsonarray for multiple news.
my requirement is to add a different page (advertisement page) inside the pager adapter. eg: after 5 swipes of the news. i should be getting the advertisement page, which is different from the news page

Answer (score 1):

First you should be make json Array with advertise data includes

For Example: json Array without advertise

> {
>     "s": true,
>     "d": [
>       {
>         "id": "203e63d7-3672-4fb7-a899-3ebd281a0e4c",
>         "title": "Title 1",
>         "description": "Description"
>       },
>       {
>         "id": "203e63d7-3672-4fb7-a899-3ebd281a0e4c",
>         "title": "Title 1",
>         "description": "Description"
>       },
>       {
>         "id": "203e63d7-3672-4fb7-a899-3ebd281a0e4c",
>         "title": "Title 1",
>        "description": "Description"
>       },
>       {
>         "id": "203e63d7-3672-4fb7-a899-3ebd281a0e4c",
>         "title": "Title 1",
>         "description": "Description"
>       },
>       {
>         "id": "203e63d7-3672-4fb7-a899-3ebd281a0e4c",
>         "title": "Title 1",
>         "description": "Description"
>       }
>     ]
>   }

now make custom class with have this parameter is,title,type,description,advertise_title and advertise_url

```
List<CustomObj> list=new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.size,i++){
int j=i;
j++;
if(j%5==0){
list.add(new CustomObj(jsonArray.get(i).getId(),jsonArray.get(i).getTitle(),jsonArray.get(i).getDescription(),1,"Advertise Title","URL")
}else{
list.add(new CustomObj(jsonArray.get(i).getId(),jsonArray.get(i).getTitle,jsonArray.get(i).getDescription,0,"","")
}

}
```

json Array with advertise list

```
{
  "s": true,
  "d": [
    {
      "id": "203e63d7-3672-4fb7-a899-3ebd281a0e4c",
      "title": "Title 1",
      "type": 0,
      "description": "Description",
      "advertise_title": "",
      "advertise_img_url": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "203e63d7-3672-4fb7-a899-3ebd281a0e4c",
      "title": "Title 1",
      "type": 0,
      "description": "Description",
      "advertise_title": "",
      "advertise_img_url": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "203e63d7-3672-4fb7-a899-3ebd281a0e4c",
      "title": "Title 1",
      "type": 0,
      "description": "Description",
      "advertise_title": "Description",
      "advertise_img_url": "https://www.pexels.com/photo/nature-red-love-romantic-67636/a.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": "203e63d7-3672-4fb7-a899-3ebd281a0e4c",
      "title": "Title 1",
      "type": 0,
      "description": "Description",
      "advertise_title": "Description",
      "advertise_img_url": "https://www.pexels.com/photo/nature-red-love-romantic-67636/a.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": "203e63d7-3672-4fb7-a899-3ebd281a0e4c",
      "title": "Title 1",
      "type": 1,
      "description": "Description",
      "advertise_title": "Description",
      "advertise_img_url": "https://www.pexels.com/photo/nature-red-love-romantic-67636/a.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": "203e63d7-3672-4fb7-a899-3ebd281a0e4c",
      "title": "Title 1",
      "type": 0,
      "description": "Description",
      "advertise_title": "",
      "advertise_img_url": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "203e63d7-3672-4fb7-a899-3ebd281a0e4c",
      "title": "Title 1",
      "type": 0,
      "description": "Description",
      "advertise_title": "",
      "advertise_img_url": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "203e63d7-3672-4fb7-a899-3ebd281a0e4c",
      "title": "Title 1",
      "type": 0,
      "description": "Description",
      "advertise_title": "",
      "advertise_img_url": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "203e63d7-3672-4fb7-a899-3ebd281a0e4c",
      "title": "Title 1",
      "type": 0,
      "description": "Description",
      "advertise_title": "",
      "advertise_img_url": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

In ViewPagerAdapter,

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
 View itemView;
 if (mList.get(position).getType() == 0) {
  //for simple item 
  itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_news, container, false);
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
  TextView text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_id);
  imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position].getUrl());
  text.setText(mResources[position].getTitle());
  container.addView(itemView);
 } else {
  //for adavertise item
  itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_advertise, container, false);
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
  imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);
  container.addView(itemView);
 }
 return itemView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create two types of fragment one is your main fragment e.g. news fragment and another will be ad fragment which will display the ads.

And based on your logic add those fragments in list before passing it to pageradapter for example .

```
    private ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    fragmentList.add(NewsFragment.newInstance());
    fragmentList.add(NewsFragment.newInstance());
    fragmentList.add(NewsFragment.newInstance());
    fragmentList.add(NewsFragment.newInstance());
    fragmentList.add(NewsFragment.newInstance());
    fragmentList.add(AdFragment.newInstance());

    NewsPagerAdapter newsPagerdapter = new NewsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentList);
    viewPager.setAdapter(newsPagerdapter);
```

And your adapter will be like this-

```
public class NewsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();


public NewsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragmentList=fragmentList;

}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragmentList.size();
}
}
```